# Warning of incompatible pointer types in a 2 dimensional array passing to a function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int r,int x,int arr[][x]);

void main()
{
 int arr[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 fun(3,3,&arr[0][0]);  
}

void fun(int r,int x,int arr[][x])
{
 int i=0,j=0;
 printf("%d",*(*(arr+i)+j));
}
```

Compiler output:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fun’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fun(3,3,&arr[0][0]);
          ^
1.c:2:6: note: expected ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(x)]’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 void fun(int r,int x,int arr[][x]);
```

Comment: how to get rid of this warning pls help
~     //warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fun’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fun(3,3,&arr[0][0]);
          ^
1.c:2:6: note: expected ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(x)]’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 void fun(int r,int x,int arr[][x]);

Comment: You should pass just `arr`, not `&arr[0][0]`

Comment: I'm passing address of 0th element of 2d array and accesing using subscript method in function

Comment: @George can you please elaborate

Comment: You could also pass `&arr[0]`, which is a pointer to an array of 3 ints, `int (*)[3]`, which is equivalent to the `int [][3]` in the parameter list.

Comment: can anyone tell me what should be the formal arguments and function prototype.

Comment: @Prawin No, you're passing the address of the 0th element of the 0th element of the 2d array. As M Oehm says, just pass `arr`.

Comment: @melpomene will this not work?

Comment: Dude, do you want to fix your code or not?

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an array of arrays of `int` (which immediately gets converted to a pointer to an array of int`; look up "array to pointer decay" if you are not sure why is this so).

`arr[0]` is an array of `int` (which immediately gets converted to a pointer to `int`).

`arr[0][0]` is an `int`.

`&arr[0][0]` is a pointer to `int`.

Your function requires a pointer to an array of `int` (you can use an array of arrays of `int`, which, as we already know, immediately gets converted to a pointer to an array of `int`, which is just what your function needs). (The parameter type is written as `int arr[][x]`, that is, an array of arrays of `int`, but it is a deception. It's a pointer to an array of `int`. Look up "parameter type adjustment" if you are not sure why is this so).

A pointer to `int` is not the same as a pointer to an array of `int`, which is why your compiler complains.

Fortunately you already have `arr`, which is an array of arrays of `int`, which immediately gets converted to a pointer to an array of `int`, which is exactly what your function needs.

I'm deliberately not touching the issue of array sizes.